# Java Strange IndexOutOfBoundsException Error

Tags: java, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my code where the problem happens, I've bolded line 90 (where the error message says the problem is originating) [edit: I can't figure out how to bold inside a code block, I marked it with an arrow instead]:

```
while ((l<=list_L.size())&&(i<=list_I.size())) {
    if (list_I.get(i).url.compareTo(list_L.get(l).src) == 0) {   //<--- LINE 90
        int firstmatch = l;
        int outgoing = 1;
        l++;

        while (list_I.get(i).url.compareTo(list_L.get(l).src) == 0) {
            outgoing++;
            l++;
        }

        l = firstmatch;
        for (int k=0; k<outgoing; k++) {
            list_R.add(new Triplet(list_L.get(l).src, list_L.get(l).dest, list_I.get(i).rank / outgoing));
            l++;
        }
    }
    else {
        sum_T += list_I.get(i).rank; //This shouldn't happen in this case...
    }

    i++;
}
```

And here is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   118981, Size: 118981
>           at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   PageRank.main(PageRank.java:90)

I don't know what is going wrong since it isn't a nullpointer exception like I would expect if something WAS wrong...

**UPDATE:**
Ok I fixed the problem in the initial location but now it's happening here:

```
for (int p=0; p<list_I2.size(); p++) {
    L2_norm += Math.pow((list_I.get(p).rank - list_I2.get(p).rank), 2); // <-- LINE 146
}
```

Error Message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   118981, Size: 118981
>   at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   PageRank.main(PageRank.java:146)

list_I and list_I2 are the same size and I have confirmed so in debugging.

Comment: In the condition check `while ((l<=list_L.size())&&(i<=list_I.size())) {` try removing `=` from both.

Comment: Exception is very clear here, you probably should change your conditions to i<list.size() not i<=list.size()

Comment: An IOOBE is as "unique" as a NPE. This question is far "too localized" and should be easily solvable with debugging -- e.g. using a debugger -- and reading the error message closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition should be :

```
while ((l<list_L.size())&&(i<list_I.size()))
```

not

```
while ((l<=list_L.size())&&(i<=list_I.size()))
```

If a list has a size of **X**, the last index of the list is **X-1**.

Comment: Ok that fixed the problem there but it's showing up again somewhere else now, added details to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((l<=list_L.size())&&(i<=list_I.size())) {
```

should probably be

```
while ((l<list_L.size())&&(i<list_I.size())) {
```

In particular, `list_I.get(list_I.size())` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because lists (and arrays) in Java are *zero-indexed* -- basically, their indices go from `0` to `n-1`, not `1` to `n`.

UPDATE:

```
for (int p=0; p<list_I2.size(); p++) {
   L2_norm += Math.pow((list_I.get(p).rank - list_I2.get(p).rank), 2);
}
```

If you're getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException here, then list_I and list_I2 *must* have different sizes, or there must be a typo somewhere else in the code.  That's really the only possibility.

Comment: This fixed it but now I have the same error elsewhere, I added info the OP.